# How does a shell interact with the terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal

I know a shell sends escape sequences (probably looked up with terminfo) to the terminal, but how does it send them? When a terminal hosts the shell, does it attach to the shell's stdout and process escape sequences it finds? Or is there some external function (system call, library, something) that `bash` has to call to tell `Konsole` to change color?

Comment: "does it attach to the shell's stdout and process escape sequences it finds?" Basically yes. "attach" might be a bit unfortunate choice of word though: the terminal emulator creates the file descriptor and gives it to the shell as its stdout.

Comment: It just writes them, at the same place as the plain text. The shell and `konsole` use a pseudo-tty to communicate with each other, which is a kind of bi-directional pipe _with quirks_. The shell (or another program) write()s `<esc>[41mfoo<esc>[m` at one end, and `konsole` read()s it from the other end and parses into the 2 escapes and the text. This kind of "in band signaling" is very inefficient and dangerous, that's one reason why "terminals" should've died long time ago. But unfortunately, they did not.

Comment: aren't there some kernel functions? about pty/pts/ttys?